# Как сделать цикл для sed на bash?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Кто может подсказать, как правильно сделать цикл для sed на bash? Или как читать файл по несколько строк? Файл может состоять из сотен строк. Нужно читать блоками по 10.

Пример скрипта:

```
cat test1.txt | sed -n 1,10p  | while read line; do
echo TEST + $line;
done

cat test1.txt | sed -n 11,21p  | while read line; do
echo TEST1 + $line;
done

cat test1.txt | sed -n 22,32p  | while read line; do
echo TEST2 + $line;
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А зачем вам тут вообще `sed`?  Вы же можете использовать
обычный счётчик:

```sh
i=1
while read line
do
    group="$(((i - 1) / 10 + 1))"
    i="$((i + 1))"
    echo "group=$group line=$line"
done < ./example.txt
```

Пример вывода:

```
group=1 line=line 1
group=1 line=line 2
group=1 line=line 3
group=1 line=line 4
group=1 line=line 5
group=1 line=line 6
group=1 line=line 7
group=1 line=line 8
group=1 line=line 9
group=1 line=line 10
group=2 line=line 11
group=2 line=line 12
```

Comment: Нужен именно pipe. Потому, что после sed вместо while может встречаться команда jq.   `cat test1.txt | sed -n 7,9p  | jq -Rn \
    --arg v1 / \
    --arg v3 server1 \
    '[inputs] | map({"{#NAME}" : $v1, "{#LIST}": ., "{#MARK}": $v3}) | { "TEST": . }'`

Comment: @perrfect  Вам лучше написать новый вопрос и описать в нём, чего вы на самом деле хотите добиться в итоге.  А то иначе будет ещё один случай [проблемы *XY*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: ок, сейчас попробую